# Fundamental group quotient of torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X=(S^1\times S^1)/\sim$, where we identify $(v,w)$ with $(-v,-w)$ (we view $S^{1}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$). My question is what is the fundamental group of $X$? Is it just $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I would work on this via the universal cover $\Bbb{R}^2$. What does this extra identification do  there in addition to the usual identification of the points $(x,y)$ and
$(x+n,y+m)$, $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}$? What kind of a group of deck transformations does that lead to?

Comment: And, you have been around here for a while now. Please check out [our guide for askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619), and if possible, add a bit more context. May be use the "hint" of the previous comment :-) Mind you, I did enjoy working out the hint myself. I hope you will, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write equivalence classes in $X=(S^1\times S^1)/\sim$ with square brackets. Also I'll think of $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Define a map $\phi:X\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ by
$$\phi[x,y]=(x^2,xy).$$
Also define $\theta:S^1\times S^1\rightarrow X$ by
$$\theta(x,y)=[\sqrt{x},(\sqrt{x})^{-1}\cdot y].$$
You can check that the maps are well-defined, and moreover that they are inverse homeomorphisms.